# How to split words by strtok function if the spaces are not equal

Tags: c++

Suppose I have to split a string into words, (i.e. "I am Mamun") [here the SPACES ARE NOT EQUAL]
I have used 1 space as delimiter in strtok function but got wrong output. Someone please explain this :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="# Timestep     No_Moles     No_Specs     CO3 CO2 HO  CHO2    O   CHO3";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," #");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " #");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

my code : http://codepad.org/eRwUDkVh

Comment: First of all please show your code here. And it is not clear what you mean saying "spaces are not equal".

Comment: Thank you for the correction. It is my first question so I didn't know that.
"spaces are not equal" means the spaces between words in the string are not equal, it works if there is only one space between them but in my input file the spaces are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the different numbers of spaces, it's that the later fields are delimited by a tab not a space.  So simply changing

```
   pch = strtok (NULL, " #");
```

to

```
   pch = strtok (NULL, " \t#");
                         ^^
```

solves the problem.

Comment: @user3772596 Great, happy to help.  Consider marking this answer as 'accepted' to help anybody else who has this same question down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You have tabs in your string not just spaces. To split properly based on spaces and tabs you should put character `\t` into the input of `strtok` too.

```
pch = strtok (NULL, " \t#");
```